# (When) can the presentation in Steinberg's Yale notes fail to give an algebraic group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, algebraic-groups, algebraic-k-theory, chevalley-groups

I'm trying to understand a remark which appears on p. 1483 of [Cohen, Murray and Taylor's "Computing in Groups of Lie Type."](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2047097) It says, "We have not used the presentations described in [7] or [30] because they define groups which are not necessarily algebraic when $\mathbb{F}$ is not algebraically closed." Reference [7] alluded to in the quotation is Carter's *Finite Groups of Lie Type* and reference [30] is [Steinberg's Lectures on Chevalley groups, Tech. report, Yale University, 1968.](http://math.depaul.edu/cdrupies/research/papers/chevalleygroups.pdf) Is there a nice example which illustrates what is meant by this remark, where the group given by the presentation in the Steinberg notes fails to be algebraic, in a suitable sense? Guidance on different relevant notions of "algebraic" and which is most likely to be operative here would also be appreciated.

Comment: the two sheeted cover of $SL(2,\mathbb{R})$ is one such example, which is not an algebraic group (it is not even linear).

Comment: This question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/69741/why-is-the-double-cover-of-sl2-mathbbr-not-algebraic is relevant to the above comment.

Comment: The question needs a more precise formulation:  (1)  Chevalley oriiginally looked at groups which are simple as abstract groups; Steinberg's lecture notes adopt a more general framework.  (2) What are the "Steinberg presentations"?    These developed out of papers he wrote before the Yale lectures and distinguish rank 1 groups from the rest.   (3) What notion of "algebraic group" are you using?   Steinberg for example relied on the 1950s Chevalley-Borel notions.   (4) Aside from groups over the real numbers, Steinberg's work led to study of matrix groups over number fields or local fields.

Comment: Also, your tags could be broadened by adding 'gr.group-theory' and 'algebraic-k-theory'.   The latter is the area especially stimulated by Steinberg's work on generators and relations.

Comment: I don't think this is a metaplectic group thing. I've clarified the question as best I can. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Is this just referring to variants of the basic fact that quotient groups such as ${\rm{SL}}_n(k)/\mu_n(k)$ (the commutator subgroup of ${\rm{PGL}}_n(k)$, generated by the "root groups") are not "algebraic" in the sense that they do not arise as the group of $k$-points of a $k$-group quotient of ${\rm{SL}}_n$?  Can you just ignore the remark which is unclear to you and see how the authors of the book you are reading use whatever it is that they are doing?

Comment: That seems plausible, but I'm looking at the presentation attached to a root system in section 6 of the Steinberg notes, and it looks to me like in the $A_1$ case it would just give $SL_2(k)$ not $SL_2(k)/\pm 1.$

Comment: It helps to include a link to the article you mention, which has its own version of the presentations (not the "Steinberg presentation" in your header): http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=2047097 (and in any case, "algebraic group" over an arbitrary field doesn't have a clear meaning).    Note too that Steinberg's lecture notes were only published informally in mimeographed form by the Yale mathematics department; a LaTeX version is posted by Chris Drupieski at http://math.depaul.edu/cdrupies/research/papers/chevalleygroups.pdf